# how to call another function in ajax post call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using a post method which displays whether particular loan number is available or not. Here is my code

Now my question is i want to call another method which pre populates the values if the loan number exists. i.e. instead of printing "Loan Number is Available" i should call a function getDetails() which is in controller that populates the values. Please help me out from this.

Comment: Just make another AJAX request inside the success callback?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the exact same structure you use now:

```
$.post("/FnmaImport/CheckLoanNumber", { "LoanNumber": num },
    function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            status.html("<font color=green>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is available!</font>");
            $.post("/FnmaImport/getDetails", { "LoanNumber": num },
                function (loan) {
                    // display the values in "loan" in some page elements
            });
        } else {
            status.html("<font color=red>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is not available!</font>");
        }
    });
```

This would make a second `POST` request under the right conditions after the result of the first one.  In that second response you would update your UI accordingly.

Of course, it might make more sense to return the data you want in the first request instead of making two requests in serial like this.  Maybe just a single request to `getDetails` which either responds with the details you want or with a message indicating that the loan number wasn't found.